# How to extract simple text and store into a file?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm writing a bash script for hetzner's cloud API, and I need to store the server's ID to a text file. After the command using it will output the below,

```
{
  "server": {
    "id": 12345678,
    "name": "servertest-101",
    "status": "initializing",
    "created": "2020-09-18T09:22:21+00:00",
```

This is just a snippet, but that's from the first line of the response.

How can I extract and store that value?

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem in your question and let us know. Its highly encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api returns in json format: You've not given much information but use jq to parse it:

```
$ cat myinput.json
{
  "server": {
    "id": 12345678,
    "name": "servertest-101",
    "status": "initializing",
    "created": "2020-09-18T09:22:21+00:00"
  }
}
$ jq -r .server.id myinput.json
12345678
```

redirect to a file:

```
$ jq -r .server.id myinput.json > myoutputfile
$ cat myoutputfile
12345678
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe output of your command to process it further as this:

```
cat yourjson.json | grep -m 1 -E -o '\"id\": [0-9]+' | cut -d" " -f 2 > yourtextfile.txt
```

First, get your json content, then send it through the grep command that extracts only part `"id": 1234567` using regular expression. Then pipe this result to cut command that splits it by a space and selects the second part, which is your value. Lastly, you redirect result of the job to the desired text file.

If you are sure that your value is going to always be the first number in the input, you can just simply select it by grep:

```
cat yourjson.json | grep -m 1 -E -o '[0-9]+' > output.txt
```